# Warning: getimagesize failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i am working on zend framework and trying to crop image after upload and save the cropped image  but i am continuously getting path error. I am working on windows platform. Please someone help me out.
I am getting this error
Warning: getimagesize(C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com/public/image/) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 21

Here is my code

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["img"]["name"])){
        $names = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
        $tmp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
        $upload_dir = "./public/image/".$names;

        $move=move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$upload_dir");

        $a="/public/image/".$names;
        $this->view->a = $upload_dir;
        $b=BASE_PATH."/public/image/".$names;

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($b);

        $newwidth = "150"; 
        $newheight = "90";
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        if($_FILES["img"]["type"]=="image/jpeg"){
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($b);
            imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width,   $height);
            imagejpeg($thumb,BASE_PATH."/public/image/".$names , 90);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be the path C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com/public/image/. in WAMP, it should be "http://localhost/path/to/file/or/folder"

Comment: i've created a virtual host

Comment: but C:\wamp\www is http://localhost

Comment: Thanks got rid of that error but now new error is generating  Warning: imagejpeg() [<a href='function.imagejpeg'>function.imagejpeg</a>]: Unable to open 'http://moduleex.com//public/image/houses-wallpapers-abstract-metal-myspace-backgrounds.jpg' for writing: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 29

Comment: imagejpeg($thumb,BASE_PATH."/public/image/".$names , 90); should probably be imagejpeg($thumb,BASE_PATH."public/image/".$names , 90); - remove the first slash, BASE_PATH already adds a trailing slash

Comment: still the error remains :(

Comment: It's solved. Actually you can't write to a HTTP location. You can only write to a local filesystem location. So i gave local path in Imagejpeg().